# How to make certain css styles responsive not the whole body

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styles, plotly-dash

I have some GUI elements in my dash application to be precised I am using the `daq LED display` element in `dash` and I am using the `css` styles below. I want to make those elements responsive because when my boss opens the app on his desktop, the elements are off. How can I make the css responsive for my screen and a larger screen. I am using a desktop app and he is using a desktop as well but slightly bigger.

```
.leed-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 1
}

.leed-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    left: 38%;
    z-index: 1
}

.leed-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    right: 26%;
    z-index: 1
}

.leed-down {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38%;
    left: 38%;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: can you specify what you really want in this question. I cannot determine what does leeds does

Comment: its a css style that places an element at a certain position on my application, but the position changes when a larger screen view it

Comment: try using `top: 0; left: 0;` then use margin in the form of `%`

Comment: top: 0; left: 0; where?

Comment: thats an example. `.leed-left { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 28%; z-index: 1 }`. I mean like this you should make the `top, left, right, bottom` to `0` and try using margins

Answer (score 0):

your code is responsive if there is only that on the screen, so i wonder if you have no other element ...
class = "ledd-xxx" are they in a div? Do they have to be responsive in relation to this container or in relation to your whole body?

if it is just in relation to the container (parent) here is a code otherwise specify a little more (please):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="leed-top"> </div>
  <div class="leed-left"> </div>
  <div class="leed-right"> </div>
  <div class="leed-bottom"> </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.leed-top { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.leed-left { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.leed-right { grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; }
.leed-bottom { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; }
```